# IOS сделать верхние закругленные углы. Не работает

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa

Всем привет! Пытаюсь сделать закругленные края у UIView, вот собственно как я это делаю

```
-(void)makeRoundedCornerRadius:(RoundedCorner)side withRadius:(CGFloat)radius forView:(UIView*)view{
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
if (side == RoundedCornerTOP){
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];

} else if (side == RoundedCornerLEFT){
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft| UIRectCornerBottomLeft cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
} else if (side == RoundedCornerRIGHT){
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomRight| UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
} else if (side == RoundedCornerBOTTOM){
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft| UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
}


CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
maskLayer.frame = view.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

При этом закругляются только левые углы, а на правые это не применяется. Что делать?

Comment: у меня нормально все отработало. попробуйте в пустом проекте воспроизвести

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась что в они закруглялись до того как размер стал "нормальным". В сториборде ширина сначала 600px

Answer (score -1):

В методе у тебя стоит проверка if - else. Это значит ты сможешь закруглить только одну сторону.

Тебе нужно добавить макрос RoundedCornerAllCorners в NS_ENUM или NS_OPTIONS
и в методе выполнить:

```
if (side & RoundedCornerAllCorners) {
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft| UIRectCornerBottomRight| UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
}
```

Либо поменяй на `if (side & RoundedCornerTOP) {` и т.д, что бы передать в метод RoundedCornerTOP | RoundedCornerBOTTOM

Надеюсь это тебе поможет.